# ExtJS 4.1.1a: Why no getApplication() method for my app?

Tags: extjs

I started with https://github.com/mclin/extjs-mvc-example, and set out to modify it so that it used Ext.application, instead of just using Ext.Create() for a subclass of Ext.app.Application.

So far so good, until I try to use the getApplication() function, which isn't there.

The code of the app definition looks like ...

```
Ext.application({
   name: 'Books',
   extend: 'some.class.name',
   controllers: ['Books'],
   ...
});
```

The result of this is a global object named 'Books', alright, but it does not define getApplication(), contrary to the Ext documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory getApplication was added after 4.1.1, 4.12 or 4.13 IIRC.

Also, you shouldn't use extend with Ext.application().

Comment: Extend with Ext.application is copied straight from their doc: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application see the section on Deriving.

Comment: Yes, but you only want to do so without a good reason, it says "Typically, applications do not derive directly from Ext.app.Application." 99% of the time you only have 1 application, so extending doesn't really make much sense in most cases.

Comment: If you look at that github, you will see the author's reason, and you can decide if it was a good one.