# ExtJS how to call the Ext.application function from view

Tags: extjs

In Ext application i have a method add_tooltip. How to access the method from the view.

```
Ext.application({

    add_tooltip: function(value, metaData) {
    metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '" data-qwidth="auto"';
    }

});
```

Comment: Controller can to call view's methods, or add listeners for it's events, but view *must not* call controller's logic.

Answer (score 2):

Executing function from the application level is possible.

Here is a demonstration of how you could call a method.

**Application Code:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',
    sayHello:function(){
        console.log('hello!');
    },
```

**Execute Method**

```
App.getApplication().sayHello()
```

However, if you are using mvc structure then usually business logic would be housed in the `controller`.

Comment: It did not work for me. i had my app name as 'TEST'..So i called like TEST.getApplication().add_tooltip(value, metaData); Got error in console TypeError TEST.getApplication is not a function

Comment: hmm, what version of extjs are you using?

Comment: I am calling from window.A renderer event for a column in a grid.

Comment: In researching it looks like that `App.getApplication()` didn't exist until 4.2. Here is a [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260646/extjs-4-1-1a-why-no-getapplication-method-for-my-app) that Evan answered and discussed.  I'd recommend moving the method to a controller if possible.

Comment: If i move the method to a controller. How would i access the method? I tried different things as suggested on internet. But did not work for me.